# Undefined method `each' for :users:Symbol thrown when using variables passed by render function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So it seems that more and more people are suggesting that it is a bad idea to actually use instance variables in controller. That you should just send the variable with render into the view.

But when I do it like this for instance:

```
def index
        users = User.all
        render 'index', users: users
end
```

Then I am unable to use the `:users` symbol in the index view and iterate over it for instance.
It will throw an error: `undefined method`each' for :users:Symbol` for me.

Is it even a good idea to try to do so? I thought I would give it a try and see how it will work out. But right now I cannot even get it to work...

Comment: So the code works using instance variables but you're just trying to see if there's a way to do it without?

Comment: Pretty much, in my application I am getting to a point where I have like 4 partials rendered to one page, and this creates a state where one method in a controller can contain many many instance variables which seems to be not considered a good way of doing things in Rails community. So I am looking for ways to do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`users` will be a variable in your view, not a symbol.

To iterate over it, you will need to call `users.each` instead of `:users.each`.

Comment: Tried that too but then it tells me that `users` is a undefined local variable.

Comment: Ahh, try wrapping `users: users` in a `locals` hash. So, your render line would be `render 'index', locals: {users: users}`

Comment: Should it not matter after Rails 4? I thought it was the same thing now.

Comment: But one more question, do you think this method is better than using instance variables then?

Comment: I think instance variables are fine, especially for the main template. Local variables are useful/should be used for rendering partials, but for a full, main template, an instance variable is fine.